# Mongoose custom validation function against race condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, race-condition

We have a calendar API for booking a slot during a day

**SlotShcema**

```
startDateTime:Date  // showing the day and the starting hour
duration:number // showing the slot duration
```

we can calculate the slot end

`endDateTime = startDateTime +  duration`

We want add a validation, so no two slot intersect, and only one user can book it .

I found costume [Async Custom Validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), but we cannot find any doc for our scenario .

The issue is to find way to solve the race condition where two concurrent saves might save conflicting bookings "transaction"  . i did my own validate function before start create the slot, but if there is a race condition it may save two slots at same time which is wrong . 
**Is there any way to solve the race condition ?**

Issue on GitHub https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5876

Answer (score 0):

Final work around worked for me is to call the function in queue with callback . it works for me, but it little slow .

This an example [JS-Promise-Race-Condition-Queue](https://github.com/almgwary/JS-Promise-Race-Condition-Queue)

---

if you want to make this solution faster  you should make queue per intersection which will make the concurrency conflict . for example date range .

You should follow the github issue link above to understand more about the situation .